# Delete presence of a User on ZKTeco F18

Tags: windev

I want to delete the presence (date and time of entry/exit) of an employee from the ZKTeco F18 time clock

so I put the following code:

```
Ok =zKemKeeper>>ClearData(MachineNumber,1)

if ok=true then
  info("successfully")
endif
```

My code works well for the K14 but for the F18 does not erase the presence even if the boolean variable is true

Thank you for giving me a lead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please not that this is an English-speaking site.

Comment: I just translated it. Need to be accepted :)

Comment: It has to be a bug in the device. I have found many like that in ZKTeco devices